# Bumblebee not working correctly

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a problem using Bumblebee and nVidia drivers 331. Is the bumblebee configured correctly? I am using it in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04
Here is results using Intel card:

```
mayor@K56CB:~$ glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
303 frames in 5.0 seconds = 60.559 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.930 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.928 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.931 FPS
```

and here is using optirun or primusrun, results are the same:

```
mayor@K56CB:~$ optirun glxgears
293 frames in 5.0 seconds = 58.461 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.930 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.929 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.928 FPS
300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.930 FPS
```

Shouldn't the results be different when using nVidia? Above is the section with nVidia drivers from bumblebee.conf:

```
## Section with nvidia driver specific options, only parsed if Driver=nvidia
[driver-nvidia]
# Module name to load, defaults to Driver if empty or unset
KernelDriver=nvidia-331-updates
PMMethod=auto
# colon-separated path to the nvidia libraries
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates
# comma-separated path of the directory containing nvidia_drv.so and the
# default Xorg modules path
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia
```

Should I remove/change the section where is about nouveau driver is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glxgears is not a benchmarking tool, so you are only seeing what is your monitor refresh ration (60Hz).

If both commands worked and produced the same output, this is and indication that the nvidia card works.